# Seeding my database as per the Entity code-first approach

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

So after I had the wizard create models from an existing database my `Configuration.cs` was

```
namespace SnakeGame.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<SnakeGame.Models.ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(SnakeGame.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
            //
            //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
            //      p => p.FullName,
            //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
            //    );
            //
        }
    }
}
```

and the model of my database was

```
namespace SnakeGame.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Linq;

    public partial class SnakeDB : DbContext
    {
        public SnakeDB()
            : base("name=SnakeDB")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<BannedIP> BannedIPs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<GameLog> GameLogs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<IP> IPs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Score> Scores { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<GameLog>()
                .Property(e => e.logText)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<IP>()
                .HasMany(e => e.BannedIPs)
                .WithRequired(e => e.IP)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Score>()
                .Property(e => e.name)
                .IsUnicode(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to follow the commented out instructions, I changed the body of `protected override void Seed(SnakeGame.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)` to

```
        context.IPs.AddOrUpdate(
            i => i.id,
            new IP { id = 1, byte1 = 4, byte2 = 35, byte3 = 241, byte4 = 179 },
            new IP { id = 2, byte1 = 172, byte2 = 16, byte3 = 254, byte4 = 1 }
        );

        context.BannedIPs.AddOrUpdate(
            i => i.id,
            new BannedIP { id = 1, ipId = 1}
        );

        context.Score.AddOrUpdate(
            s => s.id,
            new Score {  id = 1, score1 = 12, name = "John Skeet" },
            new Score {  id = 2, score1 = 1923, name = "Steve Ballmer"}
        );
```

but I'm getting errors on each of `context.IPs`, `context.BannedIP`s and `context.Score`. The error I'm getting is

> SnakeGame.Models.ApplicationDbContext does not contain a definition
>   for ...

and I'm trying to figure out how to fix it.  The full code of my Migrations folder can be seen [here](https://github.com/jamkin/Snake/tree/master/SnakeGame/Migrations). I think I've royally messied up my project by all these attempts at code-first migration. Blah.

Comment: Can you show full error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your entities are all defined in the SnakeDb context, not ApplicationDbContext  so change your seed to

```
protected override void Seed(SnakeGame.Migrations.SnakeDb context)
...
```

After you reverse engineer, you may want to move things into whatever structure you want your app to have. For me, I copy the POCOs to a separate "Entity" project and then move the EF and context stuff to a "Data" project, but you could also just move them into different folders.

Second, since you reverse engineered the database, you will need a baseline initial migration. You can either comment out the Up() and Down() code or you can generate via

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx#option1

Comment: Changing to `protected override void Seed(SnakeDb context)` yields the error "The type or namespace 'SnakeDb' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference)"

Comment: Well, yeah you need using SnakeGame.Migrations; or prefix the context name. See edited answer. Long term you should probably move your context out of the Migrations folder.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your DB with your migrations?? I have an example of the commands in my proyects

```
/*
* X DATA CONTEXT 
*/

//this command enables migrations
Enable-Migrations -StartUpProjectName X.Web -ProjectName X.DAL.Repository -EnableAutomaticMigrations -ContextTypeName XDataContext -Verbose -MigrationsDirectory:XDataContextMigrations

//this command create a new migration, please set up the name of the DBMigration
Add-Migration [NAME] -StartUpProjectName X.Web -ProjectName X.DAL.Repository -ConfigurationTypeName XUpdateDatabaseInitializer -Verbose 

//this command updates the current database
Update-Database -StartUpProjectName X.Web -ProjectName X.DAL.Repository -ConfigurationTypeName XUpdateDatabaseInitializer -Verbose 

//this command rollbacks the current Database to Specific Target applying Down() methods
Update-Database –TargetMigration: SpecificTargetMigrationName -StartUpProjectName X.Web -ProjectName X.DAL.Repository -ConfigurationTypeName XUpdateDatabaseInitializer -Verbose
```

So, if you already updated your DB I'd suggest you to completely delete your current DB and recreate it using Migrations commands...

Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you keep that script in a file or something? Is there a way of making it run when you build/compile/deploy/whatever your project through Visual Studio?

Comment: To @Retired_MSFT_Millionaire: I keep this script in a file close to Migrations directory in order to run needed command (Add,  Update or rollback) whenever I need.

To Steeve: I didn't realize on that he was using the wrong DbContext, so, don't worry, your answer is right.